# MouseMove events being created when hint is set

Tags: delphi

I am using Delphi 6 on a XP machine.

I use Onmousemove within a stringgrid to get the contents of a cell.
Then I use the cell contents to set the hint.
then I use Application.ActivateHint to display the hint.
But every time I update the hint value the OS sends another MouseMove event.
This causes pretty bad flickering of the hint.

I know the mouse is not moving but I get flooded with MouseMove events.
a mousemove causes a hint update that caused a mousemove that causes a hint update etc.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. You probably would have better experience if you  used the native hint mechanism, like intercepting a hint that will be shown in the application's OnShowHint event and then modifying it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are taking the completely wrong approach.  Instead of using the `OnMouseMove` event to manually set the `Hint` and call `Application.ActivateHint()`, let the VCL handle everything for you.

Use the `TApplication.OnShowHint` event, or alternatively subclass the StringGrid to intercept the `CM_HINTSHOW` message, to customize how the StringGrid's native hint behaves.  Either approach gives you access to a [`THintInfo`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Vcl.Controls.THintInfo) record, which allows you to customize the current hint before it is displayed/updated.  In particular, the `THintInfo.CursorRect` member allows you to set a rectangle that the VCL uses to track the mouse and decide when/if a new `OnShowHint` event or `CM_HINTSHOW` message needs to be triggered to update the current hint while the mouse is still inside of the control that is displaying the hint.  That update is much cleaner and seamless than what `TApplication.ActivateHint()` does.

For example:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.OnShowHint := AppShowHint;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.OnShowHint := nil;
end;

procedure TForm1.AppShowHint(var HintStr: string; var CanShow: Boolean; var HintInfo: THintInfo);
var
  Col, Row: Longint;
begin
  if HintInfo.HintControl := StringGrid1 then
  begin
    StringGrid1.MouseToCell(HintInfo.CursorPos.X, HintInfo.CursorPos.Y, Col, Row);
    if (Col >= 0) and (Row >= 0) then
    begin
      HintInfo.CursorRect := StringGrid1.CellRect(Col, Row);
      HintInfo.HintStr := StringGrid1.Cells[Col, Row];
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Or:

```
private
  OldWndProc: TWndMethod;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  OldWndProc := StringGrid1.WindowProc;
  StringGrid1.WindowProc := StringGridWndProc;
end;

procedure TForm1.StringGridWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
var
  HintInfo: PHintInfo;
  Col, Row: Longint;
begin
  if Message.Msg = CM_HINTSHOW then
  begin
    HintInfo := PHintInfo(Message.LParam);
    StringGrid1.MouseToCell(HintInfo.CursorPos.X, HintInfo.CursorPos.Y, Col, Row);
    if (Col >= 0) and (Row >= 0) then
    begin
      HintInfo.CursorRect := StringGrid1.CellRect(Col, Row);
      HintInfo.HintStr := StringGrid1.Cells[Col, Row];
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
  OldWndProc(Message);
end;
```

If you want the hint to be updated on every mouse move within a cell, simply set the `THintInfo.CursorRect` to a 1x1 rectangle at the current `THintInfo.CursorPos` position.  If you want the hint to be updated periodically even if the mouse is not moved, set the `THintInfo.ReshowTimeout` to a non-zero interval in milliseconds.